# Visual Studio paste as string or paste as comment

Tags: visual-studio

Programming today is mostly cut-and-paste, either your own code or snippets borrowed from different sources.

Often I need to insert multi lines of text into my code as a `comment` for documenting or as `string literal` (quote enclosed), for example a multi-line *sql* command. When pasting, VS reformat the text, even modify it to fit the language.

Is there any simple method to do it? I often resource to copy the source, paste into notepad, edit and finally copy paste into the VS pane.

Looking on the marketplace there is nothing like this. I expect to be like a 'paste special' option. To write my own VS extension is a little bit too much

Comment: I disagree: programming is not copy and paste... but as of your problem, maybe paste it in a text editor like gedit or notepad and copy/paste it again into vs?

Comment: type `/*`, hit ctrl+v, type `*/` ?

Comment: Ok, C# down, but what about VB, SQL, Phyton, PHP and so many stuff we have to deal with daily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SmartPaster2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=martinw.SmartPaster2013) extension can paste clipboard text as comments, literal string,  verbatim string and StringBuilder.

Comment: As-is on the Marketplace wont work on 2017/2019. 
Downloaded (git) source, modified the manifest to allow newer versions. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/09/26/how-to-upgrade-extensions-to-support-visual-studio-2019/